# How to make a C++ GUI program in Qt Creator 5.7 that is only 1 window, but every click makes the window have other elements- like a setup wizard

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I started making GUI Apps with Qt 5.7 around 2 weeks ago.

Until today I have made a BlackJack game, a basic mini encryption program and 1-2 more programs. Now, I could find any help on how to make an application that actually acts like a Setup Wizard- by that I mean, for example by clicking on next, a label or any elements are gone and new one appera like a progress bar and below the contents that are copied. How is that actually done?

Is it something like **`on_pushButton_clicked()`** and afterwards the usless elements are hidden like `ui->pushButton->hide();` and others show up, or is it literally made by practically "rebuilding" the window with other elements and functionalities?

Comment: Take a look at the [Class Wizard Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-classwizard-example.html) and the [License Wizard Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-licensewizard-example.html). They are using [`QWizard`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html) and [`QWizardPage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizardpage.html), this maybe faster than setting the `QStackedWidget` and connecting buttons to it yourself. . .

Comment: Cool, thank you! But in my case which is learning by doin, its kinda supposed to be harder,so that after learning the harder way, many other things become easier afterward...at least from what Ive discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: Mike's comment revealing the existence of [`QWizard`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html) and [`QWizardPage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html) makes my answer quite redundant, unless you have requirements exceeding the abilities of those widgets - or simply want to implement everything yourself - which the OP has replied that they do want to try. For everyone else, you might only need to read on if you need - or want! - to do all the heavy lifting.*

One way to do that is, as you pondered, to destroy the old contents (child widgets) of the window after each page, then repopulate it for the next.

But that's far from ideal IMO: it's wasteful, and it would require you to repeatedly destroy/rebuild things, with all the jumping around that entails, to support Back/Next/Jump to Page # buttons and all routes between different pages. That's more programming and more use of resources to keep unnecessarily tearing down and rebuilding stuff.

Your other idea about hiding is better, and I know exactly the container for this job! With this, you can build everything in advance and won't need to repeatedly remove/add children to change pages (as you would e.g. if you used a `QGridLayout`).

- Give your window a single child of the container class [**`QStackedWidget`**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html). This container takes multiple child widgets but shows only one at a time. So:
- Add to it a child container for each page of your wizard.
- Populate each child with required widgets for that page.
- Connect buttons, etc in each page to signals to do required actions...
- ...especially your Back/Next (and Jump, or whatever) buttons. Set these up so that they change the active child of the `QStackedWidget` by using the Slot [`setCurrentIndex()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop).

This way, you build the entire stack of all pages, ready to go, before ever showing the window. Then, when ready, you just show it, and everything is present and ready. Your signals, all properly connected, will take care of everything else: changing between pages, validating input, revealing labels or opening dialogs warning about missing information, etc.

Comment: I greatly thank You for the quick answer! :D

Ou...okay, so that's what I missed out.

Well then...I'll go ahead n try it! ^^

Comment: You're welcome! Let us know how you get on.

Comment: Wow....I honestly must say T H A N K u a lot for adding more explanation! :D
May I ask if it would b okay with You Sir if I get your Email just so I could show what I have done till today and aquire some criticism? Bcs of my huge amount of "I want to learn more and more!" attitude. ^^

Comment: @ChillyVanilly Sorry, no, I'm not posting an address here, SO doesn't have private messaging, and I'm bad at replying to things anyway. There's always http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get feedback and ideas for improvement on your projects - as long as they're working. Or if your programs are very Qt-specific, then I don't know, but Qt's own forums might have a similar section.

Comment: Will the anonymous downvoter have the basic courtesy to reveal themselves and tell me what is wrong here? I acknowledge that the question is rather 'help me find a tutorial', but the kernel of real question about how 'paged' windows are created seems to be a useful one and something that people are likely to search for in the future. Even if it weren't, it's extremely rude just to drive-by without explanation.

Comment: Okay, I understand sorry...
But still thank u for all of this and the quick reply! :D

Yeah and...I also noticed the -1 for some reason O.o
Weird...

Comment: not my downvote, but I'd take a wild guess that it's from the same person that voted to close as "too broad", for answering an arguably off-topic question. have my upvote for the effort, and pointing the OP to CR =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I thought it might be something like that and was coincidentally just editing my comment to speculate and somewhat defend my choice! Thank you.